# hapi returning 500 error even when axios return 201

Tags: axios, hapi.js

I am calling external API using axios with hapi server. When I debug I am seeing my axios get call is returning response with 201 status in standard axios form. Although when my hapi route return to client(browser) it is getting 500 error. My axios response look like this:

```
{
  data: '',
  status: 201,
  statusText: '',
  headers: {
   date: 'Mon, 25 Nov 2019 05:53:45 GMT',
   location: 'my-external-app-url',
   server: 'my-server-type',
   content-length: '0',
   connection: 'close'
  },
  config: {...},
  request: {...}
}
```

My hapi route

```
server.route({ method: 'GET', path: '/status', handler: (req, h) => {
  const response = axios.get(...);

  return response;
})
```

Any insight on what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: are you doing something with response after getting it from axios call?

Comment: I am not. It same as code snippet above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API call should be asynchronous.
Using **async/await** your code will look like this:

```
server.route(
{ 
  method: 'GET', 
  path: '/status', 
  handler: async(req, h) => {
    const response = await axios.get(...);
    return response;
  }
)
```